# How to get Response after POST in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have java app with API for REST.
And I make front-end for it. Now I'm working with authorization.

When I make POST request app returns me JSON message like this: 
If login and pass is right

```
{
    "result": {
        "token": "shgvojhhsifav37o5a3sebc3if"
    }
}
```

And if they are not right:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 10,
        "message": "Incorrect login or password"
    }
}
```

I can see the response in browser, but can't take it to use in JavaScript code.

And how can I get it and check for next actions.

My JavaScript:

```
controllers.controller('userAuthCtrl', ['$scope','$http',
  function($scope, $http){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/rest/api/auth/login',
            data: '?login=test&password=passwo3rd',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).
            success(function(data, status, header, config) {
                console.log(header());
                console.log(config);

                $scope.dataU = data;
                $scope.statusU = status;
            }).error(function(data, status, header, config){
                console.log(header());
                console.log(config);
            })

  }
]);
```

My test HTML is easy now.

```
<div class="testCont" ng-controller="userAuthCtrl">

</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$http ([documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)) returns a promise with two additional methods as well. `success` which you are handling correctly and `error` which you do not have defined but you can easily chain after your `success` function.

```
$http({[options]})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){})
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){});
```

If your web response is still returning a status of 200 for success or failure then you can handle it thusly in your success handler:

```
$http({})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        /*called for result & error because 200 status*/
        if (data.result){
            //handle success here
        } else if (data.error {
            //handle error here
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        /*handle non 200 statuses*/
    });
```

Based on comments, you will also need to change this:

```
data: '?login=test&password=passwo3rd
```

to:

```
data: {login: 'test', password: 'passwo3rd'}
```

This is because it is not a query string but instead part of the request body in JSON format.

Comment: I always get status 200 independent of login/pass. if i use REST Console and send POST request, i got true response.

Comment: If that is the case, look at the 2nd code block I included, based upon your data model that is being returned you can determine the logic based upon whether the field is included `result` or `error` based upon the JSON you included above

Comment: o it gave some result. 
 console.log(data.error); -- >>>  Object {code: 10, message: "Incorrect login or password"} 
But login and password is right.

Comment: It dosn't work with data: {login: 'test', password: 'passwo3rd'} only when i type data in URL.

Comment: Then append what you had originally in data to your URL and remove data

Comment: @elpofigisto did that make sense to you? making your url: /rest/api/auth/login?login=test&password=passwo3rd and removing the data field

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful for you.

```
 $http.post("Your URL").success(function(data) {
        // success
        here 


    }).error(function(error) {
        // error
        console.log(JSON.stringify("Failed to get t&c: " + error));
    });`
```